# How can i add import export to a table and also order the columns in django

Tags: django, django-import-export

I want to add import export button and at the same time order the table columns

```
class OrderEtudiant(admin.ModelAdmin):
 list_display = ('id_etudiant','nom_etudiant','prenom_etudiant','Telephone','Adresse','Filiere')
 search_fields = ('nom_etudiant',)

class userdat(ImportExportModelAdmin):
     pass

admin.site.register(Etudiant,userdat,OrderEtudiant)
```

here is the problem i can't pass three parameters

Comment: there is a class OrderEtudiant wich is helping me to display the columns on the admin panel for a specifique model called " Etudiant " also there is a second class called userdat wich is helping me to add export import button , my problem here is i want to add the two features to my table so i can import files also see the table columns on the admin panel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since [ImportExportModelAdmin is a subclass of ModelAdmin](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_admin.html#import_export.admin.ExportActionModelAdmin), you can rewrite this code snippet as follows:

```
class OrderEtudiant(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id_etudiant','nom_etudiant','prenom_etudiant','Telephone','Adresse','Filiere')
    search_fields = ('nom_etudiant',)

admin.site.register(Etudiant,OrderEtudiant)
```